# Animating a walk cycle using only Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm working on a project for a friend and he wants a pure walk cycle with only HTML/JS (no CSS). So I've tried to work it out but the image only shows up on the webpage.

**It doesn't move when I press any buttons or anything at all.**

Please show me where I went wrong. I'm used to using HTML and CSS but this is my first JS so I don't know many terms.

How it appears in the website:

[image]

My code (HTML + JS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Animation</title>
    
        <script language="Javascript">
            <!-- 
            var walker = new Array(6);
            var curWalker = 0;
            var startWalking;
            for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
                walker[i] = new Image();
                walker[i].src = "walker"+i+".png";
            }
    
            function marathon() {
                if(curWalker == 5) curWalker == 0;
                else ++curWalker;
                document.animation.src = walker[curWalker].src;
            }
            -->
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p><img src="walk1.png" name="animation"> </p>
    
        <form>
            <input type="button" name="walk" value="walk" onclick="startWalking=setInterval('marathon(),100);">
            <input type="button" name="stop" value="stop" onclick="clearsetInterval(startwalking);">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably also want to use _modern_ html and js, given that you've promised the browser to use HTML5 because of that `<!doctype html>`: `<script>` doesn't take a `type` unless it's _not_ javascript, html comments inside script tags is invalid syntax, create arrays with `let arr = []`, not `let arr = new Array()`, because arrays are dynamically sized based on what you put in them, use template strings (```src = `walker${i}.png`;```) instead of concatenation (`"..." + ... + "..."); don't use legacy `onclick`, query your document for elements that need event handing and use `addEventListener`

Comment: continuing, if you have inline script that will run immediately: put it as very last element on the page, before `</body>`, but really: put your code in a file, then load that in the head using `<script src="..." async defer></script>` so that it'll get downloaded in a separate thread, and runs only _after_ the document is ready for JS to work on. Finally, `clearsetInterval` doesn't exist, it's `clearInterval`. So I can highly recommend finding some modern tutorials (e.g. make sure to explicitly look for "HTML5" rather than "HTML", and "ES6" or "ES2020" rather than "javascript").

Comment: Some more notes: don't use `==` to compare, use `===` unless you really know why you need type-converting comparison, and if you need a general purpose button: just use `<button>` rather than a form with `<input type="button">`. (Don't use a `<form>` unless you _actually_ need to send form data from the page to a server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is how I did it get to work (I had to build my simple images with Paint in order to use them in the animation):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Animation</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p><img src="walker1.png" id="animation"> </p>

        <form>
            <input type="button" name="walk" value="walk" onclick="startWalking=setInterval(marathon,100);">
            <input type="button" name="stop" value="stop" onclick="clearInterval(startWalking);">
        </form>

        <script>
            var walker = [];
            var curWalker = 0;
            var startWalking;
            for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
                walker[i] = new Image();
                walker[i].src = "walker"+i+".png";
            }

            function marathon() {
                if(curWalker == 5)
                    curWalker = 0;
                else
                    ++curWalker;
                document.getElementById("animation").src = walker[curWalker].src;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I had to correct several typos/mistakes:

1. Put the JS just before the `</body>` closing tag
2. The first paramether of `setInterval()` must be a function name, so it must be `marathon` (you had `'marathon()`; note that leading single quote)
3. In order to get the image to be substituted it is better to access the element though `Id` instead of `name` attribute. So I changed the image to `<img src="walker1.png" id="animation">` (`animation` is now the Id) and accessed it through  `document.getElementById("animation")`

---

Now the animation starts... but stops to the last image instead of restarting to the first.

4. That was because you used to *check* the `curWalker` variable instead of performing an assignment: I put `curWalker = 0;` instead of `curWalker == 0;`

---

Almost there. The loop is complete, but the `stop` button doesn't work. Two typos are preventing this to work:

5. `clearsetInterval` doesn't exist. The function to be called is `clearInterval`
6. Javascript is a case sensitive language. You use `startwalking` variable as a parameter, but the correct variable name is `startWalking`. So you have to correct the  onclick event writing `clearInterval(startWalking);` instead of `clearsetInterval(startwalking);`

**Your animation is now complete.**

---

**Note:** as correctly noted by @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, nowadays you can avoid the use of `onclick` as you can attach events to the document (such as `"click"`) by using [`document.addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp).

Comment: you've left a _lot_ of highly questionable things in this code though.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited the language attribute and the `<!-- -->` comment inside the script tag (that I actually noticed and forgot to remove from the answer) and the array initialization. Another remark I actually agree with is the use of `addEventListener`, but I'm going to leave it unchanged because I don't wan't to change too much in OP's code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans after all I added a noted about _onclick_. That's my last edit, I promise. ;)

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot to rewrite in the original code.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thank you and Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have learner a lot from the two of you